# jsPDF generates a pdf with stretched elements inside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to use Html2Canvas together with jsPDF to generate a pdf from html. To archive that I am following [this quick tutorial](https://itnext.io/javascript-convert-html-css-to-pdf-print-supported-very-sharp-and-not-blurry-c5ffe441eb5e).

I am trying to render a simple Hello World `h1` and actually I get the pdf and the Hello World, but is to stretch, I don't know how to change it to display correctly, you can see the image below:

[image]

I already tried to change the configuration of the PDF object to something like this: `pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 2.25;`

But this seems not to change anything, I also tried some other configuration changes without success.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a @click="print">Print</a>
    <div id="nodeToRenderAsPDF">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    print() {
      const filename  = 'ThisIsYourPDFFilename.pdf';

      html2canvas(document.querySelector('#nodeToRenderAsPDF')).then(canvas => {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
        pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 2.25;
        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
        pdf.save(filename);
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The actual result I am getting is the stretched element inside the pdf, What I am expected to obtain is a PDF displaying hello world with the same size as the `h1` displayed on the browser.

Comment: You stretched the image by passing the width and height (211, 298) parameters in the addImage method. Did you try to omit those parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar problems with jspdf. Then I moved on to a library called pdfmake. You may try it,its a awesome library.

Comment: Seems very good, but does it allow css styling? I found some js style documentation but seems to basic

Comment: Yes, it does. Check out pdfmake playground